# Erro: pacote não é importado no eclipse

Tags: java, web-service, rest

Estou criando um app rest no eclipse porém estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro ao importar as classes do jersey.

**Código**

```
import javax.WebServices.rs.GET; //import da biblioteca jersey
import javax.WebServices.rs.Path; //import da biblioteca jersey
import javax.WebServices.rs.Produces; //import da biblioteca jersey

@Path("/teste1")
public class Resource {
        @GET // utilizando apenas o verbo GET, ou seja, vou apenas ler o recurso
        @Produces("text/plain") // define qual tipo MIME é retornado para o cliente
        public String exibir(){
            return "Teste Cielo 1";
        }

}
```

**Mensagem do Erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esses importes estão errados, troque o `WebServices` por `ws`, deve ter copiado um exemplo antigo.

Comment: Correção funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Códio corrigido:**

import javax.ws.rs.GET; //import da biblioteca jersey
    import javax.ws.rs.Path; //import da biblioteca jersey
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces; //import da biblioteca jersey

```
@Path("/teste1")
public class Resource {
        @GET // utilizando apenas o verbo GET, ou seja, vou apenas ler o recurso
        @Produces("text/plain") // define qual tipo MIME é retornado para o cliente
        public String exibir(){
            return "Teste Cielo 1";
        }

}
```